# The first 6 items in the navigation menu on the right side, all point to the first section

Tags: bug, estado-por-diseño, enlaces, diseño

I found a small issue with the FAQ page.

Basically, the first 6 items in the navigation menu on the right side, all point to the first section.

If you know a bit of HTML and look at the source code, you can see that the header's ID is different than the link's HREF:

> <h2 id="link-qu-tipo-de-preguntas-puedo-hacer-aqu"> ...

and:

> <a href="#qu-tipo-de-preguntas-puedo-hacer-aqu" class="section-link">¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?</a>

Is this the proper place to report [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)s?

Comment: Yes, this is the right place. :)

Comment: However, this appears to be status-bydesign (MSE): [Custom sections in FAQ don't work right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104861/custom-sections-in-faq-dont-work-right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the FAQ is written by each SE site, and it's also down in Markdown (like questions and answers), which means that those links are generated automatically. I see that this happens in other beta sites as well, maybe SE staff should fix it.